# Finding previous page Url

Tags: asp.net, url

Hi every one i need to make ads for my website in yahoo and google ok
so i need to know from which site (google or yahoo) this user come

details when user click my website ad at google i want to know that this user from google
ok please with asp.net

thanks for all

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [UrlReferrer Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx)